# jsp file inside a war application is not loading css links inside a docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, jsp, war

I build a war application with spring boot it is working fine when I run in my local machine. But when I try to dockerize it is not loading external bootstrap, CSS and js files.
[image: priject directory``]

application.properties

```
# App config
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

jsp file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="${source}/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="icon" href="${LOGO}" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
<script type="text/javascript" src= "${source}/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "${source}/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

inside controller

```
@Controller
public class RsvpHomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = {"/","home"})
    public ModelAndView home()
    { ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("profile");
      mv.addObject("source","links");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just put all of my external files in the static folder and changed JSP file to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="icon" href="${LOGO}" type="image/png" sizes="16x16">
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src= "/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```